# Android PopupWindow prevent dissmis on anchor click

Tags: android, toggle, popupwindow, dismiss

I have a popupWindow that showAsDropDown on button click and this popupWindow has setOutsideTouchable(true) and I want to toggle show the popup when I click on my button but also to dismiss when I click outside of popup. The problem is that outside touch is called before button click and my popup is hide and show after that.
Is there a way to do that ?

**FIXED**!!!

I figured out that the problem was that my popupwindow was not focused and I have to call

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Please check this out.]

If i understand in a correct way,

```
// Pop up Window showing

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_popup, null);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

 // Add setBackgroundDrawable to the pop up window to close the dialog :

        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            android.R.color.transparent));
    popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
```

using the following check, you can show the pop up as you desired

```
findViewById(R.id.topMenu).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        popupWindow
                                .showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.topMenu));

            });
```

I have checked this. It is working fine.

Comment: yes my code is similar but the `setOutsideTouchable(true)` don't work with onClick
`isShowing()` is false every time because the popup is closed before onClick is triggerd.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? You want to close the pop up window when user touches outside?

Comment: Yes I want to close when touches outside but also to have toggle anchor. Something like [this](http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2012/02/google-mobile-navigation-ui-test-feb2012-2.png) and when you click on anchor to close and open the window but also to close when you touch outside.